# Unity сцена внутри картинки

Tags: c#, unity3d

У меня есть картинка для экрана игры, но она с полями (счет, уровень и тп.). У этой картинки есть свое поле в котором по идее и должна происходить сама игра. Сейчас у меня эта картинка стоит просто как фон для сцены, поэтому игровые элементы заезжают на поля картинки. Как мне можно сделать так чтобы сама сцена находилась внутри картинки? (картинка играла роль рамки для сцены, но при этом впоследствии можно было бы разместить элементы интерфейса на самой рамке)

Comment: Звучит как проблема XY.

Comment: Если делать интерфейс не в сцене, а элементами UI на канвасе, такой проблемы не должно быть. Как у вас сделана эта рамка?

Comment: Попробуйте поместить на канвас [Render Texture](https://docs.unity3d.com/ru/530/Manual/class-RenderTexture.html), в который бы передавалось изображение со второй (не главной) камеры

Comment: Давайте немного уточню. Я пишу тетрис и у меня картинка для background'a с надписью сверху и своим собственным окошком, вот мне нужно, чтобы рендрилось именно это окошко на картинке. Сейчас у меня есть канвас с фоном, а к нему прикреплена картинка

Comment: @АлексейБрагин Вот именно для таких случаев рендер-текстура и нужна

Comment: А что мешает просто расположить и ограничить камеру под эту картинку? RenderTexture - трата ресурсов в данном случае.

Comment: То есть есть нужно отрендерить UI, потом поверх объекты сцены, а потом еще другой UI? Или есть плоский прямоугольник, как-то повернутый возможно, и нужно рендерить на него?